# How can I merge two objects of different lengths based on object's property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two object arrays of different sizes:

```
const generalValues= [{time: "08:10", general: 50}, {time: "08:15", general: 60}, {time: "08:20": general: 70},...]
const specValues= [{time: "08:00", spec: 30}, {time: "08:10", spec: 60}, {time: "08:15": spec: 20},...]
```

I would like to combine them into a list based on time:

```
const result = [{time: "08:00", general: null, spec: 30}, 
                {time: "08:10", general: 50, spec: 60}, 
                {time: "08:15", general: 60, spec: 20}, 
                {time: "08:20", general: 70, spec: null}...]
```

I have tried with reduce and map:

```
const resultMap = generalValues.reduce((item, {time, value}) => (item[time] = value, item), {})
const final = specValues.map(({time, ...rest}) => 
                  Object.assign({time}, rest, resultMap[time] ? {value: resultMap[time]} : {}))
```

But its not what I want. Please help me how can I do this?

Comment: What is `08:10`?  That's not valid JavaScript or TypeScript.  Could you make this a [mre] suitable for pasting, as-is, into a standalone IDE?

Comment: create a `Map` keyed on time (well, string). i hope you know the rest! (hint: `Object.assign`)

Comment: @jcalz this is a normal timestamp, I wrote it like this for simplicity.

Comment: Are they strings?  Then can you write them as such (encase them in quotes)? If not, then what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the concatenated arrays to group the items by `date`, then update the `general` or `spec` property if they do not exist for the given date value.

This creates a map object with an entry like { date, general, spec } for each date.

We can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the result as an array.

```js
const generalValues = [{time: '08:10', general: 50}, {time: '08:15', general: 60}, {time: '08:20', general: 70}]
const specValues = [{time: '08:00', spec: 30}, {time: '08:10', spec: 60}, {time: '08:15', spec: 20}]

const resultUnsorted = Object.values([...generalValues, ...specValues].reduce((acc, { time, general = null, spec = null }) => { 
    acc[time] = acc[time] || { time };
    acc[time].general = acc[time].general || general;
    acc[time].spec = acc[time].spec || spec;
    return acc;
}, {}))

const resultSorted = resultUnsorted.sort(({ time: a},{ time: b}) => a.localeCompare(b));  
console.log('Result:', resultSorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine! Can you please explain, what is acc in your code?

Comment: @Cronos That's going to be the result returned from `reduce`. Each iteration, you're adding onto the result, and what you return from the function inside `reduce` is going to be the `acc` in the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks @caTS, yes it's the accumulator in the reduce function.